# What is scripts.js and vendor.js files in browser network tab?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, frontend

I'm working on angular application. Once my application is initiated script.js file showing "initiated by login". After logging in it showing "initiated by the dashboard". Why it is initiating more than once?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question and add some code examples

Answer (score 4):

Both script files are part of the global scripts from angular framework.

The content of `scripts.js` comes from the scripts section in the `angular.json`.
The `vendor.js` contains npm modules being used in the `app.module.ts`.

The multiple initialization may be caused by [Module lazy loading](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules), but it is hard to say. It would be helpful, if you could provide some more information about your application, e.g. the routes from the `app-routing.module.ts`

Comment: Hi, Please check this
 https://stackblitz.com/edit/create-jvhqe1?file=app%2Fapp.routing-module.ts 
here I added my routing file code. Please ignore the remaining files.

Comment: Thank you. Oh yes, this looks like lazy loaded feature modules, an Angular key feature for large scale apps. The ``loadChildren:...` part is an indicator to prove that.
In your case I would guess, that the "initiated by login" comes from `auth.module` and the "initiated by the dashboard" comes from the `dashboard.module`. That's perfectly fine. For more information on how lazy loaded modules work, see the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules).